# How to install sqoop in Amazon EMR?

Tags: hive, sqoop, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I've created a cluster in Amazon EMR and using -emr-4.0.0. Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.6.0 and Hive 1.0.0. Need to install Sqoop so that I can communicate between Hive and Redshift? What are the steps to install Sqoop in EMR cluster? Requesting to provide the steps. Thank You!

Comment: Check out this blog post, could be of some help.  http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3UGJSBC3GVFOK/Use-Sqoop-to-Transfer-Data-from-Amazon-EMR-to-Amazon-RDS?adbsc=social_blogs_20160701_63373926&adbid=UPDATE-c2382910-6154448580691193856&adbpl=li&adbpr=2382910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the tarball of sqoop and keep it in an s3 bucket. Create a bootstrap script that performs the following activity

1. Download the sqoop tarball to the required instances
2. extract the tarball
3. set SQOOP_HOME and add SQOOP_HOME to the PATH. These entries should be made in /etc/bashrc
4. Add the required connector jars to the lib of SQOOP.

Keep this script in S3 and point this script in the bootstrap actions.

Answer (score 7):

Note that in EMR 4.0.0 `hadoop fs -copyToLocal` will throw errors.

Use `aws s3 cp` instead.

To be more specific than Amal:

1. Download the latest version of SQOOP and upload it to an S3 location. I am using **sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha** and it seems to work just fine with EMR 4.0.0
2. Download the JAR connector for Redshift and upload it to same S3 location. [This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html) might help.
3. Upload a script similar to the one below to S3

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Install sqoop and mysql connector. Store in s3 and load
   # as bootstrap step.

   bucket_location='s3://your-sqoop-jars-location/'
   sqoop_jar='sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha'
   sqoop_jar_gz=$sqoop_jar.tar.gz
   redshift_jar='RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.7.1007.jar'

   cd /home/hadoop

   aws s3 cp $bucket_location$sqoop_jar_gz .
   tar -xzf $sqoop_jar_gz
   aws s3 cp $bucket_location$redshift_jar .
   cp $redshift_jar $sqoop_jar/lib/
   ```
4. Set SQOOP_HOME and add SQOOP_HOME to the PATH to be able to call sqoop from anywhere. These entries should be made in /etc/bashrc. Otherwise you will have to use the full path, in this case: `/home/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin/sqoop`

I am using Java to programatically launch my EMR cluster. To configure bootstrap steps in Java I create a BootstrapActionConfigFactory:

```
public final class BootstrapActionConfigFactory {
    private static final String bucket = Config.getBootstrapBucket();

    // make class non-instantiable
    private BootstrapActionConfigFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Adds an install Sqoop step to the job that corresponds to the version set in the Config class.
     */
    public static BootstrapActionConfig newInstallSqoopBootstrapActionConfig() {
        return newInstallSqoopBootstrapActionConfig(Config.getHadoopVersion().charAt(0));
    }

    /**
     * Adds an install Sqoop step to the job that corresponds to the version specified in the parameter
     *
     * @param hadoopVersion the main version number for Hadoop. E.g.: 1, 2
     */
    public static BootstrapActionConfig newInstallSqoopBootstrapActionConfig(char hadoopVersion) {
        return new BootstrapActionConfig().withName("Install Sqoop")
            .withScriptBootstrapAction(
                new ScriptBootstrapActionConfig().withPath("s3://" + bucket + "/sqoop-tools/hadoop" + hadoopVersion + "/bootstrap-sqoop-emr4.sh"));
    }
}
```

Then when creating the job:

```
Job job = new Job(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
 job.addBootstrapAction(BootstrapActionConfigFactory.newInstallSqoopBootstrapActionConfig());
```

Comment: Ana, could you please explain how to load it as bootstrap step?

Comment: I am doing it in Java, I'm posting some code in my example now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from Emr-4.4.0 AWS added support for Sqoop 1.4.6 to the EMR cluster. Installation is done with couple clicks on setup. No need for manual installation.

References:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-emr-4-4-0-sqoop-hcatalog-java-8-and-more/
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-sqoop.html